# String encodiing Conversation in JSON response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, character-encoding

I have a problem of string encoding. Actually I have a application, which is in 5 languages swedish, norwegian, english, finnish and danish. In one of section of my app, I get the review of user so it's possible to come in different language format like the word in swedish nämndes.

Now the problem is i get the response of review in JSOn format and the swedish character ä came as &a and it print as &a. i want to print as ä format. same in all language character problem.

Please help me...

Comment: Use UTF-8?  Set your server to receive UTF-8, don't force your app to use something else (it's default UTF-8 I believe).

Comment: Yes, just use UTF-8 everywhere. Don't use national encodings.

Comment: @bdares I am using UTF8 everywhere but can't getting.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this when Im requesting xml data from myserver.

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString]; //Pass request text from server over to NSString 
    NSData *capturedResponseData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am using JSON and doing same encoding with UTF8 but still i can't getting

Comment: if you are getting a response string from JSON then you should be able to pass that to a NSData structure like I have done above.. passing your encoded responsestring to your NSData structure.. then use it how ever you like.

Comment: thanx. if i want to use my data, I need to encoding it and it gives same result. if you have any example than please shared a link.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** finally i change the web service character encoding. The web service Change the special word  into UTF8 style encoding like /U00.. When we display in text or label it automatically converted and display specific word.